# linking to a database (standalone) for testing purposes with html/css page

Tags: html, css, database, asp.net-mvc-4, ms-access

Hopefully what I am looking to do makes some sense.

I am working on a project that will hopefully simplify an existing tool that is used on a regular basis. It is highly outdated both in style and language.  What I have done so far as designed a sample layout to test the functionality of this tool. The HTML and CSS code is here for view as it does not display well as embedded html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="w3-container w3-black w3-center">
<h2 class="w3-text-red">Tool</h2>
</div>

<div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin-top">

<div class="w3-col" style="width:20%;">
<div class="w3-container">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-btn">A***0</button>

<div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
<div class="w3-modal-content">
<div class="w3-container w3-card-8">
<span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span>
<p>Name:</p>
<p>Service 1:</p>
<p>Service 2:</p>
<p>Service 3:</p>
<p>Service 4:</p>
<p>Devices:</p>
<div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin-top">
<div class="w3-col" style="width:20%;">
<a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="" alt="Device 1"></a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin-top">
<div class="w3-col" style="width:20%;">
<img src="" alt="Device 2">

</div>
</div>

<div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin-top">
<div class="w3-col" style="width:20%;">
<img src="" alt="Device 3">

</div>
</div>

<div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin-top">
<div class="w3-col" style="width:20%;">
<img src="" alt="Device 4">

</div>
</div>

<div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin-top">
<div class="w3-col" style="width:20%;">
<a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="" alt="Device 5"></a>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When this is run in Chrome (used as corporate settings for IE block some code) you get a very small sample of the page (again simple testing purpose here).

This is using straight HTML/CSS3 to bring up a page with buttons. When the buttons are clicked the bring up a MODAL that will display specific information. As of now all the tags are very generic as this is for work and certain info is proprietary. What I am looking to do (again simple, needed only for testing) is when the button is clicked to bring up the MODAL that info will be passed from a database to fill in the info for that specific listing in the MODAL.

Example: Service 1 in MODAL needs to pull info from a database for a specific client/customer.

I am looking for the easiest way to do this on a local machine.  I am not looking for building the entire database or deploying on corporate servers at that is way above my pay-grade and experience.

I currently have very limited experience in asp.net MVC4 and SQL (Meaning I have just started learning both and have completed the MVC Music Store Tutorial) So I think that I could build something with that but wanted to know if there was an easier way to do so with just html/css and possibly MSACCESS as I have access to that while working.

I am currently building the DB in ACCESS and that should be done in the next day or so depending on how busy I am with my other job functions.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all for you time.

Edit: Is this possible using JavaScript and a Database file or would i definitively need to be running some type of server (even IIS) to make this possible.  I am very limited in the tools I have on my work system.

Answer (score 0):

HTML and CSS deal with presentation and layout, comprising the front-end.  Your database and *application language of choice* (C#, PHP, etc) comprise the back-end.

It sounds like you would want to either develop this as an MVC project or use JavaScript to perform AJAX requests.  The AJAX request would receive data from some sort of controller action or application page and display it where you want.

There are lots of different ways of getting and manipulating data; it's all very subjective and depends on your requirements.  This is a question that you will need to answer on your own.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I know linking to the SQL database using asp.net MVC is easy enough Just difficult to work on as the work systems don't have VB Studio and can not be installed (corporate system). I have edited my original post to hopefully clarify what i am hoping to do.

Comment: If you could somehow generate JSON data at a specific location, you could perform an AJAX call to the file (/folder/example.json) and manipulate the data with just JS.